# Newline confusion moving from typescript -> dynamoDB -> embedded C

Tags: javascript, c

I am getting confused in how to deal with newline characters in this fairly confusing scanario:

**Stage 1**

On a windows machine, I ran a chunk of node.js code that pushed certificates into a dynamoDB database in AWS. In the database, the newlines seem to be working:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDCzCCAfMCFENRSInSPfdsalkewqsfdgffdrlijvdssnoawererwq3DQEBCwUAMG4x
DTALBgNVBAMgrsrqefjfjdshsisdgdshjkfdiudfoiaskjhsdfjhkfgsdaksaW5ndG9u
...
```

**Stage 2**

I read the files from another node application in the cloud. If I print the values out now, they look like this:

```
{ "cert" : "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\nMIIDCzCCAfMCFENRSInSPfdsalkewqsfdgffdrlijvdssnoawererwq3DQEBCwUAMG4x\r\nDTALBgNVBAMgrsrqefjfjdshsisdgdshjkfdiudfoiaskjhsdfjhkfgsdaksaW5ndG9u\r\n
    ... " }
```

So, the line feed & newlines have been replaced by \r\n in the resulting json object.

**Stage 3**

After doing some stuff, I save the files again in the cloud as json objects. They now look like this:

```
{"state":{"desired":{"cert":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\nMIIDCzCCAfMCFENRSI ...
```

**Last Stage**

Finally, I want to consume these files in an embedded C environment and save the certificate string locally. However, when I read the files into the application, they are interpreting the \r\n as a string literals, not as an actual newine. I can prove this by printing the string out in the console. The \r\n are still there.

Sorry for the long winded explanation, but I wanted to show each step. My goal is to have the string in C at the end with proper newline characters working. Any idea how I achieve this??

Comment: \r\n only has a meaning to C during compile time. If you load some json in run-time then \r\n won't have any special meaning unless you code it like that.

Comment: Of course. So, \r\n is just like any other 4 chars. Got it!

Comment: How do you extract the certificate on the last stage? Do you use a JSON parser? There is no way a correctly implemented JSON parser will produce 4 characters (`'\\'`, `'r'`, `'\\'` and `'n'`) from the sequence `\r\n` listed in the JSON you posted  as the outcome of stage 3.

Comment: Using the json parser supplied with esp_aws_iot v3.1 (point taken: it is a terrible json parser). So yes it does produce exactly that sequence. '\\' is interpreted at compile time as the raw character '\'.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lundin pointed out, "\r\n" is basically garbage that needs to be removed. The root problem (why I'm even thinkin about this) is down to the absolutely awful JSON parser that comes bundled with esp_aws_iot. Which I perhaps ill-advisedly persevered with.

This is the code I ended up using. It chops out any special characters, except newline which is replaced with an actual newline:

```
// REFORMAT CERT
int i, j = 0;
for (i=0; i < strlen(cert); i++) { 
    if (cert[i] == '\\') {
        i++;
        if (cert[i] == 'n') {
            cert[j++] = '\n';
        }
    } else {
        cert[j++] = cert[i];
    }
}
cert[j] = '\0';
```

So while this solves the immediate problem, a better solution would be to use a proper JSON parser.